# Polynomial greatest common divisor algorithm

Tags: algorithms, modular-arithmetic, modules, divisibility

I look for an algorithm  for **Polynomial greatest common divisor**.
I saw [this at Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_greatest_common_divisor) but I didn't understand where is the algorithm.

If you have other source for this algorithm, or you can write to me, or tell where I can find it at [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_greatest_common_divisor) (at the link)...

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

to find gcd($f,g$) with $deg(g) < deg(f)$, write $f = g q_1 + r_1$ with $deg(r_1) < deg(g)$; then
\begin{equation*}
gcd(f,g) = gcd(r_1,g)
\end{equation*}

Again, write $g = q_2 r_1 + r_2$ with $deg(r_2) < deg(r_1)$; then
\begin{equation*}
gcd(f,g) = gcd(r_1,g) = gcd(r_1,r_2)
\end{equation*}

Continue this process until you get $gcd(r_n,0)$, which in this case you will have $gcd(r_n,0) = r_n$, and so $gcd(f,g) = r_n$.

Comment: I don't understand what is $r$ and $q$? Can you explain more please?

Comment: They are polynomials: let's do an example

Consider $f = x^3 + x + 2$ and $g = x + 3$. By dividing them you get
\begin{equation*}
f = g (x^2 - 3x + 10) - 28 = g q_1 + r_1 \text{ } (note deg(r_1) = 0 < 1  deg(g) )
\end{equation*}
so $gcd(f,g) = gcd(r_1,g) = gcd(-28,x+3)$.

Again,
\begin{equation*}
g = r_1 ( -\frac{1}{28}x - \frac{3}{28}) + 0 = r_1 q_2 + r_2
\end{equation*}
hence $r_2 = 0$, so $gcd(r_1,g) = gcd(r_1,r_2) = gcd(-28,0) = -28$.